# libgdx BitMapFont not working

Tags: libgdx

I am trying to use BitMapFont in libgdx based game.I do this:

```
BitmapFont font;
this.font = new BitmapFont();
render{
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0x64 / 255.0f, 0x95 / 255.0f, 0xed / 255.0f,
            0xff / 255.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Gdx.app.log(TAG, " FPS: " + Gdx.graphics.getFramesPerSecond());

    batch.setProjectionMatrix(CameraManager.camera.combined);
    batch.begin();
    font.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    font.draw(batch, "Time", 4, 4);
    batch.end();
}
```

And my camera is managed as:

```
public class CameraManager {

public static OrthographicCamera camera;

public CameraManager(){
    camera = new OrthographicCamera(Constants.VIEWPORT_WIDTH, Constants.VIEWPORT_HEIGHT);
    camera.viewportWidth = (camera.viewportHeight)
            * ((float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth() / (float) Gdx.graphics
            .getHeight());
    camera.position.set(camera.viewportWidth / 2,
            camera.viewportHeight / 2, 0);
    camera.update();
}

public void resize(int width, int height) {
    camera.viewportWidth = (camera.viewportHeight)
            * ((float) width / (float) height);
    camera.update();
}
```

}

But instead of text, several rectangles are displayed whose color is the color I pass to setColor().I really have no idea whats happening here. Most of the tutorials use this simple piece of code.But it is just not working for me.

Please advise.

Comment: As @Valentin says, please include the code that create/initializes your `font` object.  Also, does the font work without the color specified?

Comment: You're getting something on screen, but it looks like the system can't find the "glyphs" for your characters.  You could try different text strings (try some numbers or punctuation).  You could try loading the font file directly (see what it using here: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/gdx/src/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/BitmapFont.java#L71)

Comment: I guess default font works only when we work in pixel dimensions.I coded
official Drop libgdx tutorial(https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Extending%20the%20Simple%20Game), and changed the viewport dimensions to small values(5x5),and accordingly made following change:

game.font.draw(game.batch, "Welcome to Drop!!! ", 2.5f, 2.5f);

Same issue occurred here too.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend downloading some .ttf fonts and passing them in into the bitmap font object like so

```
BitmapFont font = new BitmapFont(Gdx.files.internal("fontfile.ttf"));
```

Here are a lot of great .ttf fonts you can download https://www.google.com/fonts